# have a 04 Acura with a 2.0 engine has manual 5-speed transmission drives good through 1 through 4th gear won't go into 5th

Tags: manual-transmission, acura

5 speed manual transmission drives good through 1st through 4th gear won't go into 5th it's a 04 Acura with a 2. engine would it be fine to drive 1 through 4th or is something else going out or would it hurt transmission

Comment: Either the shift linkage has a fault, or there's a fault within the gearbox. If it's the shift linkage, it's *probably* OK to keep driving the vehicle as long as the linkage doesn't fail further. On the other hand, if the fault is within the gearbox, it's probably a *very bad idea* to keep driving the vehicle. Other than an external physical examination of the linkage, I don't know how to diagnose this.

Answer (score 4):

David's comment is correct.  It's either the linkage, a damaged or bent shift fork, or something wrong with a synchronizer or internal transmission component.

Try shifting into 5th with the engine off, vehicle not moving, and the clutched pressed in.  If you still can't get into 5th easily, it's most likely mechanical linkage or a shift fork.

If you can get into 5th easily enough when not running, it's probably a failure of a synchronizer or part of the gear train. When running 40-50 mph in 4th gear, try shifting into neutral, release the clutch, then press the clutch pedal again and attempt to shift into 5th.  If you can get into 5th with this "double clutch" method, it's probably a bad synchro unit.

Comment: A standard driving skill when I learnt... hence the old joke « I know four gears now, crunch first and crunch second... »

Comment: @SolarMike  I suspect you and I are both of an age that involve driving vehicles that had no fancy synchro bits ... perhaps an older truck or farm tractor where "double clutch" was *de rigueur*, or perhaps a heavy-duty racing transmission with straight-cut gears and no tolerance for extra weight or fancy bits that could compromise reliability.  Perhaps all three.  At my age the "Grandpa" stories are much of what I have left . . .